# Difference between deep q learning (dqn) and neural fitted q-iteration

Tags: reinforcement-learning

What is the difference between deep q learning (dqn) from "Human-level control through deep reinforcement learning" and neural fitted q-iteration from "Neural Fitted Q Iteration - First Experiences with a Data Efficient Neural Reinforcement Learning Method"? 
Links are below, respectively.
https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14236.pdf
http://ml.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/former/_media/publications/rieecml05.pdf

From my understanding they seem to be doing the same thing except dqn updates the target network every C steps.

Answer (score 3):

Beside the existence of the target network in DQN, Neural Fitted Q Iteration only uses the available historical observation and does not perform any exploration. In other words, there is no need to have an environment and there is just loop over train steps:

```
D = historical data
for e in range(epochs):
  b = get_batch from D
  train_step(b)
```

while in DQN there are two loops:

```
D = []
for e in range(max_episode):
  done = False
  s = env.reset()
  while (!done)
   a = policy.get_action(s)
   s',r, done = env.step(a)
   D.append(s,a,r,s')
   if D.size > min_replay_mem:
    b = get_batch
    train_step(b)
```

In the `train_step` both obtain a `target` value and then use a euclidean loss function. To get the `target` value, DQN uses the target network, though fitted Q iteration uses the current policy.

Actually, Neural Fitted Q Iteration is considered as a batch-RL algorithm which assumes there is not any available environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What difference makes having an environment besides performing exploration?

Comment: Once you have an env, you are able to `easily` test the performance of the trained model. If you do not access an env, you need to follow `off-policy` policy evaluation, e.g. importance sampling which are hard to measure in problems with long-horizon.

Comment: For example look at this paper: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6538-safe-and-efficient-off-policy-reinforcement-learning.pdf

Comment: I am trying to implement a deep reinforcement learning algorithm for classical control task like keeping room temperature, charge of battery, etc. within certain limits. Which algorithm would you suggest, DQN, NFQ, PPO, DDPG, etc.? Do classical control problems inherently have or have no environment?

Comment: It is a very broad question, I would create another question for each of those problems. Each of the algorithms that you mentioned has some strengths and some cons, although if you have a constrained problem neither of them works. You might want to consider http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/perkins02a/perkins02a.pdf  or https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.10528 to incorporate constraints into your RL model.